# Cannot re-add CT from hub to a list after deleting it via PNP script

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp

I added a CT, published from the CT hub, to a SharePoint site page library. I then used script to first remove the CT from the list.

```
Remove-PnPContentTypeFromList -List "SitePages" -ContentType "MY_Site_Page"
```

I then deleted it from the site:

```
Remove-PnPContentType -Identity "MY_Site_Page" -Force
```

I then tried to manually add it to the list - I can see the CT from the available CT to choose from and add it. However, clicking "ok" nothing happens. No error message and the CT is not added to the list. I have tried other sites where I havent run this script on without any issues.

Any ideas on why I cannot add the former deleted CT to the list manually?